# Focus outline breaking on right side - not wrapping element fully

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using Chrome.... anyone know what is causing the focus blue line to break on the right side? There is no element pushing outwards to cause this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share any more of the code or a url? That's pretty hard to debug without being able to use something like Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML and CSS in a working demo it seems very possible that the width of your "Date of Birth" label is too long. The extra space in the outline looks like it is aligned very closely with the top of that label.

Comment: Good catch, but doesn't seem to be pushing past the parent element

Comment: Its the exact height and alignment of the extra space you're seeing. You're correct that the red box doesn't appear to be pushing past but I'd bet that label is still the culprit. Can you provide a working code example through codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm only asking for the relevant code, if you can recreate it in one of those then we can debug.